# adding projection to conjuction

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria, nhibernate-projections

How can I add a projection to this code? I am trying to sort my results according to date created or last updated.

```
    var c = new Conjunction();
    c.Add(Restrictions.Where<InstructionTask>(x => x.IsOpen == _setDefaultStatusIfNotFound(status)));
```

//error adding this projection:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) || sort.Equals("created", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        c.Add(Projections.Property<InstructionTask>(x => x.DateCreated));
```

I am passing in my `Conjuction` to another method that will handle the retrieving of tasks i.e. `var tasks = GetCollaboratedTasks(c);`

Answer (score 0):

A conjuction is just a group of filters that will be ANDed together. It is not related to projection or sorting. You need to stick it in a DetachedCriteria or ICriteria.

Answer (score 0):

To sort your results by the property `DateCreated` use:

`criteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc(Projections.Property<InstructionTask>(x => x.DateCreated));`

As Oskar said, a Conjunction can only be used to apply filters.